# how does aws datapipeline scheduling work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I noticed some strange behavior by AWS data pipeline.
The `Execution start time` is before the `scheduled start time`. Please refer to the screenshot below.

Am I missing something here ?

Is this acceptable behavior for AWS data pipline ? What are the recommended way to avoid this ?

[image: Datapipeline console]

Answer (score 0):

Data Pipeline here is recording creation of instance as Execution start time. But it does not start execution (Running state) before Scheduled start time. You can verify this by clicking on the instance, view all fields, it has additional info.

This is definitely misleading. Data Pipeline needs to fix the recording of timestamps.